# Ruby on Rails / MySQL: how do I do a search on an array using OR?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Both privacy and users are arrays.
I've taken out some logic to show the important stuff.

```
  named_scope :non_employees_and_beloning_to_users, lambda { |args|
    privacy = args[0]
    users = args[1]
    { :conditions =>  ["(visibility = ? && user_id = ?)", privacy, users] }
  }
```

but basically, the above generates the below, and when typed into a MySQL editor thing, no results show up. so, I came to believe this isn't the correct method for searching for stuff in mySOL with an array?

```
SELECT * 
FROM `proposals`  
WHERE visibility = '1,0' && user_id = '-1,8,9,11';
```

I want it to have the effect of

```
visibility = (1 or 0 ) AND user_id = (-1 or 8 or 9 or 11)
```

Comment: Arrays of id's or of objects? :)

Comment: of ids. objects are too big =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems that you have a comma separated list of values in visibility and users you could use MySQL's IN() function. Something like:

```
visibility IN (1,0) AND user_id IN (-1,8,9,11)
```

(see here for more info on IN(): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

Alternatively you could convert visibility and users to Ruby arrays and then generate similar SQL code manually.

Comment: They are ruby arrays. how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If `args[0]` and `args[1]` are arrays of ids, you just do this:

```
named_scope :non_employees_and_belonging_to_users, lambda { |args|
  privacy = args[0]
  users = args[1]
  { :conditions =>  ["visibility IN (?) AND user_id IN (?)", privacy, users] }
}
```

You need to wrap your `?` placeholders in parens for SQL's `IN` to work. This should generate:

```
SELECT * FROM `proposals` WHERE visibility IN (1,0) AND user_id IN (-1,8,9,11);
```